# Hadoop-2.6.0 Namenode not getting formatted

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have just install Hadoop 2.6.0, While formatting name node, it halts at following lines and no exit code returns.

> STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
> STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_79 
> ************************************************************/
>
> 15/08/28 18:45:22 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
>
> 15/08/28 18:45:22 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [–format]
>
> Usage: java NameNode [-backup] | 
>
> [-checkpoint] | 
>
> [-format [-clusterid cid ] [-force] [-nonInteractive] ] |
>
> [-upgrade [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved] ] | 
>
> [-upgradeOnly [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved] ] | 
>
> [-rollback] | 
>
> [-rollingUpgrade <rollback|downgrade|started> ] | 
>
> [-finalize] | 
>
> [-importCheckpoint] |
>
> [-initializeSharedEdits] |
>
> [-bootstrapStandby] | 
>
> [-recover [ -force] ] | 
>
> [-metadataVersion ]  ]
>
> 15/08/28 18:45:22 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
>
> /************************************************************
> SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at workstation/127.0.1.1
> ************************************************************/

I am not be able to debug out of it, when run start-dfs.sh and start yarn.sh it start all demon except NameNode.

Comment: Sid, could you please provide command you used and relevant contents of $HADOOP_HOME/logs/hadoop*namenode*.log file ?

Comment: did you use -format or --format?

Comment: Shubhangi, i had used -format

Comment: @Shubhangi is right - you used the equivalent of --format (long hyphen instead of the normal short one. This can happen when using a word processor for code instead of a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you used a wrong command.The commands related to hdfs are available in this [url](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#namenode)

Use any of the following command command

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

OR

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

Comment: i had checked this but no luck... :(

Comment: It's because the OP used `–format` instead of `-format`  (long vs short hyphen). See my answer for further info

Answer (score 0):

> 15/08/28 18:45:22 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [–format]

This looks like the same problem detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697622/how-to-format-the-namenode), with solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697622/how-to-format-the-namenode/51703827#51703827).

The problem is that you used the long hyphen "–" instead of the short hyphen (minus symbol) "-"

One way that this can happen is by using a word processor instead of a text editor.