# How to format the NameNode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have followed the instructions to set up a Hadoop cluster in pseudo-distributed mode, as per the instructions on apache.org: [Hadoop: Setting up a Single Node Cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html);

I am using Hadoop 2.7.7 and everything works OK except for the formatting of the NameNode. The instructions say:

```
 $ bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

However, this outputs the usage info and shuts the node down:

```
.
.
18/08/05 19:20:02 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [–format]
Usage: java NameNode [-backup] |
    [-checkpoint] |
    [-format [-clusterid cid ] [-force] [-nonInteractive] ] |
    [-upgrade [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved<k-v pairs>] ] |
    [-upgradeOnly [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved<k-v pairs>] ] |
    [-rollback] |
    [-rollingUpgrade <rollback|downgrade|started> ] |
    [-finalize] |
    [-importCheckpoint] |
    [-initializeSharedEdits] |
    [-bootstrapStandby] |
    [-recover [ -force] ] |
    [-metadataVersion ]  ]

18/08/05 19:20:04 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

However, if I use the (apparently deprecated)

```
 $ bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

......it works !!!

Why is this happening, and how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

## "**`bin/hdfs namenode -format`**" is not the same as "**`bin/hdfs namenode –format`**" !!

Don't believe me ? How about now?

```
`bin/hdfs namenode -format`
`bin/hdfs namenode –format`
```

The command that you wrote:

```
$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

is NOT the command that you actually submitted !

From the output you gave:

```
18/08/05 19:20:02 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [–format]
```

Notice the dash in from of the "format" argument: `[–format]`. This is using `U+2013 : EN DASH` which is a "long dash" that you might get if you typed the command in a word processor. The normal dash used in coding is the short dash/minus/hyphen:`[-format]` which uses `U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS {hyphen or minus sign}` and should be the character you get when you type the "minus" key (at least, on my keyboard)

My guess is that you didn't type the command or copy/paste it from the link, but from a word processor instead.